# Thorup : What is the meaning of super distance?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

While reading Thorup's Algorithm to solve SSSP problem, I have one point that I can't understand: super distance.

It says: "For each vertex we have a super distance $D(v)\geq d(v)$"

$d(v)$ must refer the shortest distance from origin to $v$, but what is $D$ ?

Is it just a distance value from origin while calculation until $D(v)=d(v)$ ?

Comment: How about giving a link?

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=316548

Comment: Can you update the post with this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says: "For each vertex we have a super distance $D(v)\geq d(v)$"

"Super" refers to the "$\ge$" relation between $D$ and $d$. In other words, since $D(v)\ge d(v)$ where $d(v)$ is the distance from $v$ to $s$, $D(v)$ is called super distance.

> Is it just a distance value from origin while calculation until $D(v)=d(v)$ ?

Correct. It is just a distance that approximates the shortest distance from the source from above, which will become that shortest distance at the time $v$ is moved to $S$, the set of vertices whose distances have been settled.